# How does youtube introduce newer version on the same url?

Tags: php, cookies

i want to make newer version of my website and ask users to try it, but i want the same url

is this the best cleanest way to do it?

```
   // code executes if user asks to make the new version the default.
setcookie("newversion", "true", mktime(0,0,0,12,31,2011));
```

this is the `/index.php`

```
if($_COOKIE['newversion'] == "true") {

    /**
    * load the new version of the site.
    *
    **/
    exit();
} else {

    /**
    * load the older version of the site.
    *
    **/

}
```

i did not found any tutorials or questions of this sort, so please help.

Comment: Setting a cookie via `setcookie()` will NOT affect the _COOKIE superglobal until the NEXT page load. The superglobals are initialized/populated BEFORE your code starts executing, and then are not touched by PHP again.

Comment: You can't set and access a cookie in the same instance.

Comment: i know it was just an example, this is not the question i will edit, it was just an illustration, i just need to know if this the cleanest way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is precisely the way youtube implements HTML5 video (via the `PREF` cookie). Since you often only want to change a part of your site, the code may look like:

```
$prefs = array('version'=>'1', $html5=false);
$prefs = array_merge($prefs, parsePrefs($_COOKIE['PREFS']));
if ($prefs['version'] == '1') {
  old_header();
} else if ($prefs['version'] == '2') {
  new_header();
}
```

Alternatively, you can of course two initially diverging controller paths (like in your example) that end up calling the same helper functions.